# What is the best way to understand a sentence that has multiple "not"s thrown into it?

Tags: logic

I'm studying for the GMAT, and the Critical Reasoning section has options such as

- *Joe's Snack Shack will NOT become more popular UNLESS its exterior and interior are updated significantly.*

Is there a way to re-write the above sentence?

Could I re-write that sentence to say "Joe's Snack Shack will become more popular if its exterior and interior are updated significantly"?

If so, could I negate that for test purposes and say, "Joe's Snack Shack will NOT become more popular if its exterior and interior are updated significantly"?

If I cannot re-write the original sentence to what I had written above, then what would the negated version of the original sentence be?

What about this sentence--"the decrease in soda consumption is NOT LARGELY the result of a reduction in consumption of soda by people who were already consuming little soda"?

How do I simplify this "soda sentence" to not have "NOT"s in it, but have the same original meaning?

Is there a good book somewhere that helps us use logic to understand complex sentences?

I would like to add that the negated sentence, "Joe's Snack Shack will NOT become more popular if its exterior and interior are updated significantly", helps me identify the opposite of the original sentence, thereby allowing me to see if the original sentence is an assumption that the author needs to make a particular conclusion. If the negated sentence does offer an alternative path to the conclusion, then the original sentence needs to be an assumption that the author has to make to draw the conclusion. I probably should have added the actual question as well to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: It's far too late to begin now if you've never devoted any study to complex sentences. That's like asking what you can study to learn mathematics beyond grade school. But it's not really your fault; Anglophone students are not taught anything about their language except a bunch of things not to say, but no reasons why or how.

Comment: I don't understand the fourth sentence: *If so, could I negate that...* So far as I can see, you started with ***X will not happen unless Y***, which you quite reasonably "re-wrote" to ***X WILL happen if Y*** in your third sentence. But the fourth sentence is effectively ***X WILL NOT happen if Y***, which completely reverses the original meaning.  In short, ***IF** doesn't mean **UNLESS***.

Comment: Contrary to what the banner on top of the page says, the problem with this question is not that it is unclear, and it is unlikely that it could be improved by 'adding details'. The real reason for closing it is that the question is well within the domain of exercises in introductory logic courses (including the relevant test-preparation courses), which puts it outside the domain of this site.

Answer (score 2):

They complicating factor is you have a comparison as well as a direct negation.

In this case the negation of “unless” would be “only if”. “Unless” makes it a necessary condition without it being a sufficient condition.

Your first rewrite adds the sufficient condition - if he does this, then that will happen. To make it only necessary, but not sufficient, you would say “x will happen ONLY IF y is done. This includes the idea that doing y will not automatically cause x to happen.

So your negated statement would be:
Joe's Snack Shack will ONLY become more popular IF its exterior and interior are updated significantly"?

So there’s no guarantee that doing that will help, only that NOT doing it will lead to failure.

Your 2nd sentence is trickier, because it is the phrase itself that needs to be negated

Consider the original statement like this:
“X [the decrease in soda consumption] is NOT LARGELY Y [the result of a reduction in consumption of soda] by Z [people who were already consuming little soda]”

then the negation becomes:

“X [the decrease in soda consumption] is NOT LARGELY Y [the result of a reduction in consumption of soda] by NOT Z [people who consume a lot of soda]"

Now, remove the double negative:

“X [the decrease in soda consumption] is LARGELY Y [the result of a reduction in consumption of soda] by Z [people who consume a lot of soda]"

“the decrease in soda consumption is LARGELY the result of a reduction in consumption of soda by people who consume a lot of soda”

Hope this helps.

Comment: 'Joe's Snack Shack will not become more popular unless its exterior and interior are updated significantly' may well be said not to entail ''Joe's Snack Shack will become more popular if its exterior and interior are updated significantly' by logicians, but I'd say that most people would interpret pragmatically and think that improvements **are** being vaunted as popularity increase factors.